# Minify 2.1.5 works on localhost but not on live server due to document root issue

Tags: php, minify, document-root

**The problem:**

My `/min/` files are in different places for my local and live server:

- `localhost/min/`
- `/mnt/foo/bar/hello/example.com/web/content/min/` (from `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`)

Min works fine on my `localhost` but after uploading the same files via ftp to my live server I get a 400 bad request error. This is clearly due the different document roots.

**What I've tried:**

Changing the `$min_documentRoot = ''` variable in `config.php` file to

`$min_documentRoot = '/mnt/foo/bar/hello/example.com/web/content/'`

Still gives the same errors.

**Additional info**:
My requests look like this:

`src="/min/b=js&amp;f=jquery.min.js,bootstrap.min.js,site.js"`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579412/minify-php-minifyserve-http-1-0-400-bad-request

Comment: @Nikos I'm new to this and I have no idea how to do that :P

Answer (score 0):

how are you minifying? is it with zip?

make sure that the live and local servers both have the same setup. especially, make sure that they both have the required minification functions available to them. for example, the Zip PHP functions are not installed by default in Fedora installations.

check the online server's httpd error log

Comment: make sure that your online server satisfies the requirements that Minify has then:

1: PHP 5.1.6 / command-line tools require 5.3
2: The commonly installed zlib extension is recommended for HTTP encoding functionality.
3: Version 1.0.1 required PHP 5.2.1+.

A quick way to determine differences between your online and offline servers is to create a file on each one containing <?php phpinfo();?> then compare the contents of the table it generates

Comment: Those are a lot of tables I have to check through. Do I only need to look at the ones you've pointed out?

Comment: first thing: check the server logs. there might be something obvious there.

then check the phpinfo() differences. zlib (the zip libraries) are an obvious thing to check for